# Amazon EC2 -> S3 traffic limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

My Amazon EC2 (Windows / t2.Large) server uploads ~200K files to S3 (bucket is in the same region as the server). After a few hours of ~100 files a minute the upload slows down to ~30 files a minute with no obvious reason. Pausing the process for a few hours will make it go fast again. Does Amazon put a limit on this traffic? Any other reason for the speed loss?

Here is my upload code:

```
        string S3_KEY = S3TargetFileName;

        S3_KEY = S3FolderName + "/" + S3_KEY;

        S3_KEY = S3_KEY.ToLower();
        PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest()
        {
            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
            BucketName = BucketName,
            Key = S3_KEY,
            FilePath = LocalFullPath
        };
        var client = GetS3Client();
        client.PutObject(request);
```

Comment: If this is a one-off or infrequent need, you might prefer using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). It has a `aws s3 sync` command that can copy files in parallel (see [config documentation](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/awscli/topics/s3-config.rst)).

Answer (score 2):

You have probably run out of CPU credits for your instance. The T2 instances are [Burstable Performance Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/#burst). Once your CPU credits are depleted, you will experience a slowdown.

You can see your CPU Credit Balance from the EC2 console (select your instance, then go to the Monitoring tab). It should probably near zero now.

For sustained workloads that should not be slowed down, you should switch to a different family of instances that are not burstable (e.g. the M4 family).

Comment: Sounds likely. Also worth mentioning that Network Bandwidth is limited for every EC2 instance and the amount of bandwidth provided is based upon the Instance Type. Larger instances receive more network bandwidth. However, this wouldn't explain the gradual slowdown.

Comment: I suspected so. Where can I see the bandwidth limit per instance type?